# Query on table A to find the number of overlapping jobs for each job

Tags: database-design, data

Table A:

| job | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1:30 | 2:30 |
| B | 1:45 | 2:15 |
| C | 2:45 | 3:45 |
| D | 0:50 | 2:50 |

Table B:

| job | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1:30 | 2:30 |
| B | 1:45 | 2:15 |
| C | 2:45 | 3:45 |
| D | 0:50 | 2:50 |

Sample output:

| job | start_time | end_time | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1:30 | 2:30 | 2 |
| B | 1:45 | 2:15 | 2 |
| C | 2:45 | 3:45 | 1 |
| D | 0:50 | 2:50 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT {columns from t1}, COUNT(*)
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.start < t2.end AND t2.start < t1.end
GROUP BY {columns from t1}
```

If adjacency must be treated as overlapping then use weak unequiation operators.

Comment: Thanks for the effort @Ergest Basha but the numbers are not comming up correct from the above query. However, I sort it out and got the desired result, posing my query below.

Comment: SELECT j1.job,j1.start_time, j1.end_time, COUNT(*) AS overlapping_jobs_count
FROM jobtable j1
JOIN jobtable j2 ON (j1.job <> j2.job) -- Exclude self-joins
WHERE j1.start_time < j2.end_time
AND j1.end_time > j2.start_time
group by j1.job,j1.start_time, j1.end_time